# Compiling Racket bytecode hangs

Tags: racket

I was trying to compile Racket bytecode to excecutable. However, when I typed `racket parser_rkt.zo`, then there was nothing showing but the cursor kept flashing...What reasons can it be?

btw, I have no source code, but just the compiled one.

Comment: This may sound snide but... did you type "racekt" (as your question suggests) or "racket"? Can you be more concrete about the specific file names you used (I was unable to duplicate your problem)? Finally, a message like this will probably get a faster and more helpful response if posted to the racket users list.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the typo....has edited..and the full name...and an email sent to the list :)

Comment: hmm....It seems that I use `raco exe parser_rkt.zo` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the program is simply waiting for input.  Running `racket parser_rkt.zo` does run that program, so if it doesn't produce anything, that's probably just how the program behaves.

Comment: You guess right, I didn't realize it at the beginning. (was expecting the command to compile:)